# How to edit specific value of CSV file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Say I had this csv file:

```
Name, Age, Year, Nation
John, 23, 1944, Africa
Fred, 45, 1922, China
Bob, 23, 1999, Japan
```

How would I specifically change say the number 45 to the user input, or anything else for that matter.

For example if the user input was 56, how would I write it so it replaces the 45 with 56, without hardcoding it.

Comment: What code have you tried so far for this?

Comment: you may refer to this answer: [How can I replace a value in an existing excel csv file using a python program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912693/how-can-i-replace-a-value-in-an-existing-excel-csv-file-using-a-python-program/36913137#36913137)

Comment: I have read that thread, how would I actually replace something with a variable?

Comment: I have figured it out however it edits the entire column, how do I edit a specific row of that column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to let the script read in the .csv file. Then, I assume you have a way of letting the user (or the script) pick the appropriate data row for this process, i.e. through their name.

You should take a look at the [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) class. It will allow you to approach every row as a dictionary. Then, it's basically a matter of getting the user input (`new_val = input("Insert new value: ")`), replacing that value with the value that was in the row and rewriting the file, which could be done by using the [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) class.